# Read in a DER formatted private key using System.Security.Cryptography

Tags: c#, c, openssl, cryptography, der

I have an existing private key that is being loaded in a C application via an OpenSSL module.

```
int PRIVATE_KEY_LEN = 512;
RSA *rsa;
unsigned char PRIVATE_KEY[] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, ... }
const unsigned char *Key = PRIVATE_KEY;
rsa = d2i_RSAPrivateKey(NULL, &Key, PRIVATE_KEY_LEN);
```

From what I understand the private key is in a DER format and I'm now trying to use the key in a separate .NET application.

Is there a way to load this into a `RSACryptoServiceProvider` without using a third part library in C#?

I have a feeling I'm supposed to create a `RSAParameters` and load the relevant bytes from the key like so but not really sure which bytes I'm supposed to be using

```
int PRIVATE_KEY_LEN = 512;
private byte[] PRIVATE_KEY = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, ... }
rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
var rsaParam = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
rsaParam.Modulus = PRIVATE_KEY.Take(PRIVATE_KEY_LEN).ToArray();
rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParam);
```

Am I way off?

Comment: You have to convert the format Microsoft uses or use third party library such as Bouncy Castle.

Comment: C# needs the ket with the subjectPublicKeyInfo. You need to use OpenSSL's `i2d_RSAPublicKey_*` or `i2d_RSA_PUBKEY_*` to write the subjectPublicKeyInfo, and not just the public key.

Comment: Check this blog post ".NET RSACryptoServiceProvider PEM + DER Support": http://www.cnblogs.com/adylee/p/3611461.html